# How to call a function inside yii framework controller from core php file?

Tags: php, yii, yii-components

I am working in yii framework.I am getting stuck at a point where I have to call a function inside controller in yii framework from core php file. Actually I am going to create html 
snapshot.

my folder structure is

```
seoPravin--
--protected
  --modules
    --kp
      --Dnycontentcategoriescontroller.php
      --DnycontentvisitstatController.php
--themes
--start.php (This is my customized file)
--index.php
```

1) Code of start.php file :--

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
     <html>
     <head>
        <?php 
        if (!empty($_REQUEST['_escaped_fragment_']))    
        { 
            $yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/yii_1.8/framework/yii.php';
            require_once($yii);
            $escapeFragment=$_REQUEST['_escaped_fragment_'];
            $arr=explode('/',$escapeFragment);
            include 'protected/components/Controller.php';
            include 'protected/modules/'.$arr[0].'/controllers/'.$arr[1].'Controller.php';

            echo DnycontentcategoriesController::actiongetDnyContent();  //gettting error at this point

            ?>
            </head>
            <body>
                <?php 
                    //echo "<br> ".$obj->actiongetDnyContent();
        }
                ?>
            </body>
    </html>
```

2) yii side controller function : This function work for normal but when I am calling `using escaped_fragment` it gives error

```
public static function actiongetDnyContent()
    {

        if (!empty($_REQUEST['_escaped_fragment_']))//code inside if statement not working
        {
            $escapedFragment=$_REQUEST['_escaped_fragment_'];
            $arr=explode('/',$escapedFragment);
            $contentTitleId=end($arr);
            $model = new Dnycontentvisitstat();  //Error got at this line
        }
        else  //Below code is working properly  
        {
            $dependency = new CDbCacheDependency('SELECT MAX(createDateTime) FROM dnycontent');
            $content = new Dnycontent();
            $content->contentTitleId = $_GET['contentTitleId'];
            $content = $content->cache(2592000,$dependency)->getContent();
            $userId=105;
            $ipAddress=Yii::app()->request->userHostAddress;
            echo "{\"contents\":[".CJSON::encode($content)."]} ";
            $model = new Dnycontentvisitstat();
            $model->save($_GET['contentTitleId'], $userId, $ipAddress);
        }   
    }
```

error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Dnycontentvisitstat' not found in
>   C:\wamp\www\seoPravin\protected\modules\KnowledgePortal\controllers\DnycontentcategoriesController.php
>   on line 289

code is working for normal url but not working for _esaped_fragment

Comment: If you are calling controller functions directly from a view like that you are doing something very wrong. I have no idea what this code is trying to do, but how it does it is an example to be avoided. Consider stepping back and thinking it over.

Comment: Delete it all,  and rewrite it from scratch after reading yii guide. Jon is completely right.

Comment: yeah! you are right. I am changing my code.thanks..

Comment: +1 for learning something from this

Answer (score -1):

It is a very bad practice but you can do a HTTP self request, like this:

```
include("http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/path/?r=controller/action&_param={$_GET['param']}");
```

Check http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php to see how to enable HTTP includes.